# Team Foundation Build 2010 - Check-in changed file during the build process

Tags: tfsbuild, checkin

In my build workflow I change the assembly version information in AssemblyInfo.cs for some class libraries. How can I check-in my changes at the end of the build process? From what I see there is no such activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a blog post by Ewald Hofman on how to do exactly what I want:

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx

Comment: You probably should accepts this answer, so that it's marked as "answered" when looking at the question...